# Laravel 5 - passing variable to relationship model

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

If I have below models:

```
class User extends Model{
    protected $someDataFromExt = ['taskID0' => 'test', 'taskID1' => 'ting'];
    public function tasks() { return $this->hasMany('Task'); }
}

class Task extends Model{
    protected $appends = ['ext_data'];
    public function user() { return $this->belongsTo('User'); }
    public function getExtDataAttribute(){ return $this->external_data; }
}
```

I would like, when I do: `$tasks = auth()->user()->tasks->all();` I want to pass `$user->someDataFromExt` (based on task ID) to task model, so I later in my `$tasks` variable I can access:

```
foreach($tasks as $task){
    echo $task->ext_data;
}
```

Which will return data that was given from user model earlier?

Is this possible? how?

Answer (score 0):

Not completely following why the task data is being stored on the user model, but I think what you’re asking can be achieved via your accessor method on your task model, providing you make the someDataFromExt public:

```
<?php
class Task extends Model {
     public function getExtDataAttribute()
     {
          return $this->user->someDataFromExt['taskID' . $this->id];
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I think about this before but the variable is protected, so it is not accessible, and i try not to change that. I there a way instead of accessing parent model, the parent model load the variable...

Comment: You can keep it protected and just use a getter method instead?